# Python Shelve could not retrieve object

Tags: python

I tried to store objects and was able to do it successfully..But I have problems, while treiving it..Error is given below

person.py

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, pay=0, job=None):
        self.name = name
        self.age  = age
        self.pay  = pay
        self.job  = job

    def lastname(self):
        return  self.name.split()[-1]

    def giveraise(self,percent):
        #return self.pay *= (1.0 + percent)
        self.pay *= (1.0 + percent)
        return self.pay
```

Manager.py

```
from Person import Person

class Manager(Person):
    def giveRaise(self, percent, bonus=0.1):
        self.pay *= (1.0 + percent + bonus)        
        return self.pay
```

update_db_classes.py

```
import shelve
from Person import Person
from Manager import Manager
bob = Person('Bob Smith', 42, 30000, 'software')
sue = Person('Sue Jones', 45, 40000, 'hardware')
tom = Manager('Tom Doe',  50, 50000)

db = shelve.open('class-shelve')
db['bob'] = bob
db['sue'] = sue
db['tom'] = tom
db.close()
```

Code to retrieve the objects..
dump_db_classes.py

```
import shelve
db = shelve.open('class-shelve')
for key in db:
    print(key, '=>\n  ', db[key].name, db[key].pay)

bob = db['bob']
print(bob.lastName())
print(db['tom'].lastName())
```

Error:
C:\Python27\Basics>dump_db_classes.py
bob =>
   Bob Smith 30000
sue =>
   Sue Jones 40000
tom =>
   Tom Doe 50000

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Basics\dump_db_classes.py", line 8, in 
    print(bob.lastName())
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'lastName'

Comment: Firstable you have to read python basics before asking this question!

Answer (score 1):

Python is case-sensitive.  You call `bob.lastName()` but the `Person` method is `.lastname()`.  The error message is trying to tell you this:

```
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'lastName'
```